# Calculating element with most occurrences in list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have

```
dict = {
    0: ['9', '3', '3', '5', '1'],
    1: ['9', '4', '1', '2'],
    2: ['3', '4', '1', '5', '5'],
    3: ['4', '4', '5', '5', '1'],
    4: ['2', '8', '9', '5', '1']
}
```

take an example `0:['9', '3', '3', '5', '1']` here `3` has more number of occurance so iw ant to update enter list with only 3 so at index 0 becomes [3]

if every element has equal weight like `1: ['9', '4', '1', '2']` there will be no change

another `['4', '4', '5', '5', '1']` returns `['4','5']`

i tried using `collection.counter` but donot know  how to update the original dict with max repeated

```
for i,j in dictonary.items():
    dictonary[i]=Counter(j)
```

expected output:

```
{0: ['3'], 1: ['9', '4', '1', '2'], 2: ['5'], 3: ['4'], 4: ['2', '8', '9', '5', '1']}
```

**Edit:** the list size may vary

```
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]->[1,2]
[3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6]->[4,6]
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean. Do you want to find the key-value pair by the number of repeats? So `0` is max here? Why is `3` not a candidate? It has two `'5'` values in the list.

Comment: Are you asking to find the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics))? That's different from the "max".

Comment: @MartijnPieters at index 0. 3 was repeated many times so i want to update index 0 element with 3 as value. sorry abt my english

Comment: What happens if you have something like `['4', '4', '5', '5', '1']` ?

Comment: @Holt ['4','5'] it will return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import *

d ={0: ['9', '3', '3', '5', '1'], 1: ['9', '4', '1', '2'], 2: ['3', '4', '1', '5', '5'], 3: ['4', '5', '0', '4', '3'], 4: ['2', '8', '9', '5', '1']}

for i,j in d.items():
    c  = Counter(j)
    top = c.most_common(1)
    if top[0][1] > 1:
        d[i] = [ top[0][0] ]

print d

{0: ['3'], 1: ['9', '4', '1', '2'], 2: ['5'], 3: ['4'], 4: ['2', '8', '9', '5', '1']}
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from collections import *

d = {
 0: ['4', '4', '5', '5', '1'], 
 1: ['9', '4', '1', '2'], 
 2: ['3', '4', '1', '5', '5'] 
}

for i,j in d.items():

    c  = Counter(j)

    result = []

    for x in c:
        if c[x] > 1:
            result.append(x)

    if result:       
        d[i] = result

print d

{0: ['5', '4'], 1: ['9', '4', '1', '2'], 2: ['5']}
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from collections import *

d = {
 0: ['4', '4', '5', '5', '1'], 
 1: [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4], 
 2: ['3', '4', '1', '5', '5']
}

for i,j in d.items():

    c  = Counter(j)

    longest = c.most_common(1)[0][1]

    if longest > 1:

        result = []

        for x in c:

            if c[x] == longest:
                result.append(x)

        d[i] = result

print d

{0: ['5', '4'], 1: [1, 2], 2: ['5']}
```

Comment: ['4', '4', '5', '5', '1'] what abt this.

Comment: one more thing my list range is not fixed .as example i gave list of length 5 actually i have list vary to any length . how can i check that example [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4] should return [1,2]

Comment: as per above comment it returns 1,2,3 but it should be 1,2

Comment: why does max(c.values()) dont work. is there any explanation chk this http://repl.it/UCj modefied ur . it works fine

Comment: `max(c.values())` - what result do you expect ? `max(c.values())` give the same value as `c.most_common(1)[0][1]` so as for me `max(c.values())` works correctly.

Comment: `most_common(1)` is special function of `Counter()` to get max value(s). It shound be faster then `max(c.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're looking for the mode of each element in your dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter

def mode(L):
  result = []
  for x in L:
    if Counter(L)[x] == max(Counter(L).values()):
      if x not in result: result.append(x)
  return result

for item in dict:
  dict[item] = mode(dict[item])
```